# Bidirectional Charging on Macbook Pro (2019)

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, charging, displayport

I am using a bidirectional USB-C to Displayport cable (CableCreation PN: CD0738) to connect my 2019 Macbook Pro to a BENQ PD2700U monitor. The description stated that this would allow not only video and audio through the display up to 8K, but also would allow charging at the same time due to the bidirectional function of the cable. So far the image and audio are great and as described, but the charging is not working.

Does anyone have experience with this? Is there a way I can enable my Macbook Pro to allow the incoming charging through this? I needed a good cable anyway, so if it only does the single function that is fine, but was hoping to limit my usage of the ports and charge and display through a single connection.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Are you sure that your monitor support this feature?

Comment: Do you have the specs on that particular cable/adapter?  It doesn't show up on the [mfg website](https://www.cablecreation.com/index.php?s=CD0738&eshopsearch=all)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can enable my MacBook Pro to allow the incoming charging through this?

There's is not setting to allow incoming charging because charging is, by design, allowed.  It's a defacto function of the port.

I think you're misunderstanding how the [Thunderbolt port](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/308378/119271) works.  It's a multiplexing of several signals - DisplayPort, USB 3.2, PCIe, and Power.  It doesn't stop doing one when it's functioning as another.  In other words, it doesn't lose the ability to charge and be charged if you plug in a monitor.

For your Mac to be able to be charge while your monitor is plugged in, you need the following:

- A monitor that supports it (i.e. the [LG UltraFine](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27md5kl-b-5k-uhd-led-monitor) monitors that were designed for Apple/macOS)
- **An [active Thunderbolt/USB-C](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/395873/119271) cable**.  Note that all Thunderbolt 3 cables are USB-C cables, but only quality USB-C cables are Thunderbolt. Active cables support 40Gbs transfer at 2m (6.5 ft.) while passive cables, which are less costly are limited to .5m (1.6 ft.).

A quick review of the [technical specifications page](https://www.benq.com/en-us/monitor/designer/pd2700u/specifications.html) for your monitor makes no reference to "power delivery" or "charging."  It's also not mentioned in the product description.  If you look at the LG UltraFine specifications page from the link above, you'll notice it specifically mentions "Thunderbolt 3 with 94W PD."

[image]

If your monitor doesn't send power to charge your computer, no cable in the world will make this work.